# Publish r-markdown to rpubs directly

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I use R version:

```
              _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.1                         
year           2018                        
month          07                          
day            02                          
svn rev        74947                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
nickname       Feather Spray
```

and use R.markdown, as I want to publish a tutorial in Rpubs. When I was using a previous R version, I was able to do so, by going upper right in the script section and hitting on "Publish Document" (RPubs would appear as an option). Now it requires that I can connect to an R Studio server, which I don't wish to do.

How can I connect directly to Rpubs and publish there directly?

Comment: Your R version likely doesn't matter, the feature you are speaking of is an Rstudio feature. I'm running version 1.2.907 and still have the Rpubs option.

Comment: My Rstudio version is ‘1.1.456’.

Comment: Then perhaps you can just update to a newer Rstudio version (like mine).

Comment: I am not sure where can I find this version for Windows?